# ImportXLM on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having a hard time extracting only the title of a Spotify playlist name to google sheets.

Here is the link: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX0jgyAiPl8Af?si=xeoueUTuR0uNfk4kYSmnZg

Here is my current code: =IMPORTXML(B2,"//head/title")
(B2 is the link)

Here is what it prints: Peaceful Guitar | Spotify Playlist

I am trying to figure out how to only get the peaceful guitar part. I'm not sure how I would go about this so any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about retrieving the value from `meta` tag using a xpath?

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@property='twitter:title']/@content")
```

- In this case, the cell "A1" has the URL of `https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX0jgyAiPl8Af?si=xeoueUTuR0uNfk4kYSmnZg`.
- Or, you can also use `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@property='og:title']/@content")`.
- Or, you can also use `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='media-bd']/h1/span[@dir='auto']")`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- For example, when you want to retrieve the value of `Peaceful Guitar` using your formula, you can also use the formula of `=TRIM(INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//head/title"),"|"),1))`.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: @Robert Brooks Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.